# Заполнение массива определенными числами 0, 1 или 5

Tags: c++, математика, случайные-числа

Условие: В массиве X, размерность которого не превышает N, каждый элемент равен 0, 1 или 5. Переставить элементы массива так, чтобы сначала располагались все нули, затем все единицы, а затем все пятерки. Дополнительного массива не заводить. Размер массива вводится пользователем. Заполнение массива осуществить, используя либо датчик случайных чисел, либо «ручной» ввод пользователя.

Как заполнить вручную и отсортировать понятно, но не могу додуматься, как датчиком случайных чисел это сделать.

Comment: Как заполнить одну ячейку массива понятно? Как получить случайное число понятно? А теперь "оба окурка вы давите вместе".

Comment: Почему нет идей?) Вы же сами ответили в вопросе. "в случайном порядке" - значит записываете в массив случайное число из 3

Comment: Как случайно получить 0 или 1 понятно:
A[i]=0+rand()%2;
Но как 5?

Comment: Можно получать 2 и делать вид, что это 5. В смысле не записывать 2 и представлять на ее месте 5, а если выпало 2, то записывать 5.

Comment: Благодарю, отличная идея

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Опять не втискиваюсь в комментарий...

Вариантов - масса. Например, самый тупой:

```
int get() {
    switch(rand()%3)
    {
    case 0: return 0;
    case 1: return 1;
    case 2: return 5;
    }
}
...
A[i] = get();
```

Вариант самый эффективный:

```
int x[] = {0,1,5};
...
A[i] = x[rand()%3];
```

Или даже

```
A[i] = "\x00\x01\x05"[rand()%3];
```

Наконец, вариант экзотический:

```
int get()
{
    int n = rand()%3;
    return (3*n-1)*n/2;
}
...
A[i] = get();
```

И еще с десяток подобных :)